# Spring Boot + Jasypt fails to build

Tags: spring, jasypt

everybody!

In my Spring Boot app I use Jasypt for dealing with encrypted properties. 
But today my build had faied with an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor]: Factory method 'textEncryptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.encrypt.EncryptorFactory.create(EncryptorFactory.java:51) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$RsaEncryptionConfiguration.textEncryptor(EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$RsaEncryptionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80fb9d1d.CGLIB$textEncryptor$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
```

What is interesting, that it only fails on my machine. My colleagues checkout from CVS and do *mvn clean install* without any problems.

We use this version of Jasypt

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I switch to an older version like 1.16, everything works fine.
Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: When it works on your colleagues' machine and not on yours, then focus on finding out what exactly the difference is between your and your colleagues' machine. Maybe you have a different configuration file? What exactly is failing; a unit or integration test? Try debugging the test.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find out what the problem is?